# Is my ghusl valid?

Tags: ghusl, self-purification

Assalamu alaikum.

I did ghusl this morning, but I'm in a doubt about it.

What happened is I washed all of my body, wetting each and every hair. What went wrong is I forget to rinse my nose and do gargle. After coming out of the bathroom and wearing the clothes, I remembered it and then I did it both.

So, I'm in confusion whether my ghusl is valid or do I have to do it again?

Please answer only if you are sure.
JazakAllah Khyar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform Ghusl? And is my ghusl valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47944/how-to-perform-ghusl-and-is-my-ghusl-valid)

Answer (score 1):

**In hanafi school of thought, this kind of ghusal is valid.** Also, I heard from a big hanafi scholar that if someone pushed you or you slip into clean water, you ghusal is valid too...

But **in salafi/ahlul-hadith school of thought**, what they say is that you need to have the intention (niyat) for ghusal, as it is also an amal and every amal is dependent on niyyat (keep in mind niyyat is not saying it in words by mouth, niyyat is what is in your heart when you do something), and also you must do it as the prophet did, there is an easy procedure which hanafis call sunnat but **salafi scholars say ghusal is not valid without that procedure and without niyyat.** I don't know the views of other madhabs on this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it, brother. Yes, NIYYAT is very important. I do it ever time before taking ghusl!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is valid. I asked an alim and he said that the ghusl is valid but it is better to do it again.

Alhamdulillah!