# Can I shower after Ghusl?

Tags: ghusl

Aoa!

If I go into the shower with intention of doing Ghusl-e-Janaabat, and wash my head and neck, and rinse mouth and nose, then wash right side of the body, and then the left side; after this if I take a shower with soap without getting out or anything, will my Ghusl be valid i.e., will I be Junub after getting out of the shower or not?

Also, is it obligatory to not face even 45° in the direction of Ka'bah during Ghusl? Because my shower place is built such that I face Ka'bah while showering but I try to turn myself away as much as I can, so will my Ghusl be valid in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: Ghusl is valid as long as its obligations are met. Washing in some sequence or facing some direction has no effect on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform Ghusl? And is my ghusl valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47944/how-to-perform-ghusl-and-is-my-ghusl-valid)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's okay, as long as you've finished your ghusl, to shower as you normally would and use soap, shampoo, etc.
And while studying shafi'i I never encountered anything about having to face away from qibla.