# Am I considered pure?

Tags: taharah, ghusl

If I am in a state of major impurity and I perform ghusl with water only allowing the water to flow through my entire body and after the ghusl the smell of impurity is still there is my ghusl considered invalid?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform Ghusl? And is my ghusl valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47944/how-to-perform-ghusl-and-is-my-ghusl-valid)

Answer (score 0):

If you see najis in you body visible then you are not pure and the have to do ghusl again. If you just get smell of najis and don't see anything in your body you are pure.

Answer (score -2):

in general using soap and a like is ok if you find that water alone doesn't remove the smell so you do a normal shower using these substances (soap and a like) then you do the ghusl and for that here is a good article about how it is done:

https://www.wikihow.com/Perform-Ghusl