# Question about ghusl

Tags: halal-haram, source-identification, ghusl

I made ghusl after a wet dream with the intent of uplifting the major and minor impurity
is it enough of an intention. If someone could help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform Ghusl? And is my ghusl valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47944/how-to-perform-ghusl-and-is-my-ghusl-valid)

Answer (score 0):

It differs by madhab. In Hanafi fiqh, intention for ghusl is not Fard, just sunnah. So you could jump in a lake and have performed a valid Ghusl. I think Shafi says it is Fard. I don't know about the other two.

Comment: That might be hanafi view.

Comment: Please consider elaborating or supporting your claims by evidences. Also read [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Intention is not a requirement for ghusal. If ypu just walk in the shower and complete the actual 3 farzs then your ghusal is complete. But making intention is mustahab, soyou should do it but if you don't, it's all good.