# Validity of this ghusl

Tags: salat, wudu, ghusl, intercourse

After sexual intercourse I made ghusl the the way of sunnah and made sure it was valid. I put water over my hair, body, private parts (which had semen on them) and made sure I was wet all over my body. I only used water (no soap). After finishing my ghusl, I put on some clothes and then went to pray salah.

After I finished with my salah I noticed that my penis was sticky. It turns out that semen and water react to a sticky substance (I did research on this). It is almost like glue and is very, very hard to wash of.

After that I quickly went and made ghusl again, but the substance did not come of with only water. After putting some soap more than once it finally came of, and after my penis dried it was not sticky.

Since I did ghusl with water and fulfilled all the fards (I put water all over my body, washed my private parts, etc.) was it valid?

Comment: After the ghusl was done and you prayed salah, did you re-read the salah?

Comment: What do you mean “read” salah. After performing my first ghusl I prayed salah. After I was finished I discovered the sticky substance on my penis. After that I did another ghusl and washed the substance of with soap and not only water.

Comment: I meant after the 2nd ghusl did you pray the salah again?

Comment: No I did not. Should I make it up? 

I read your answer. From my own knowledge you are right. My opinion is that even my first would be valid, because it met the 3 criterias (even if the semen became a sticky substance).

Comment: I’m not too sure because you weren’t aware at the time and you made intention that you were clean to pray. On the safe side it would be best to re read it. Apologies I can’t go into further detail

Comment: No problem. May Allah reward you. Ameen.

Comment: Jazakallah, Ameen!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform Ghusl? And is my ghusl valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47944/how-to-perform-ghusl-and-is-my-ghusl-valid)

Answer (score 1):

From my own knowledge I understand that for a ghusl to be valid it must meet the 3 obligatory criteria which is to make the water reach the nose mouth and then wash all the body including the head making sure all parts of the body is washed. This must be done with clean water. Intention is also a requirement depending on what school of thought you follow.