# Is my ghusl valid? Please help!

Tags: sawm, wudu, ghusl

The fard acts of ghusl is washing nose, washing mouth, and water in all parts of body.

I just finished my menses (period) so I had intention to make ghusl because I want to pray and start fasting (it is holy month of Ramadan now).

I went in the bathtub, washed my private parts with water and soap. Then washed my hands with water and soap. Then washed in my nose 3 times and mouth 3 times. I then put water on my hair with shampoo and washed it very well. Then put soap all over my body (except my private parts because I already washed them) and washed with water.

I got out of the bathtub and wiped my body with a towel, put clothes on, and hair dried my hair using hairdryer. Then I did wudu and put face moisturizer on (I have to put it on because of my dry skin).

Is my ghusl valid correct?

Please tell me if it is! I want to pray, start fasting, and read Quran from mus'haf.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform Ghusl? And is my ghusl valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47944/how-to-perform-ghusl-and-is-my-ghusl-valid)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Washing your body, and making sure that the water reached all your body parts including rinsing your mouth, and nose is enough for valid ghusl.

https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/96925/%D9%8A%D9%83%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%BA%D8%B3%D9%84-%D8%AA%D8%B9%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B3%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1