# Is this ghusl janabat valid?

Tags: ghusl

For ghusl janabat to be valid, is standing in the shower sufficient or do you have to physically rub your entire body with water? I know the steps are below but I am trying to clarify step 5 as I have bad ocd. Thank you

1. Form the intention in the heart to purify oneself from major impurity: janabah (impurity following sexual discharge), menses or nifas (postpartum bleeding).
2. Then say Bismillah and wash the hands three times, then wash any dirt from the private part.
3. Then do wudu as for prayer, a complete wudu.
4. Then pour water over the head three times, and rub the hair so that the water reaches the roots of the hair.
5. Then wash the body, making sure that the water reaches all parts, starting with the right side of the body and then the left, and rubbing it with the hands so that the water reaches the entire body.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform Ghusl? And is my ghusl valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47944/how-to-perform-ghusl-and-is-my-ghusl-valid)

Comment: Yes it does thank you so much. I have ocd so I am trying to work with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, All steps are correct

Only one thing is important to keep in notice. That private parts shouldn't be touched during the 5th step. if happens you will have to do "Wadu" again.

Also if possible, went yourself by taking a light shower, use shampoo or soap whatever is required.. then do wadu and wash your body according to Ghusal process. Because there are many chances of touching your private body parts if you will start taking ghusal at the first step and later use soap and shampoo.

And also, dont' look at yourself while you are doing ghusal. And
Last, better you do ghusal sitting instead of standing.

JazakALLAH Khair.